# Machine Learning conferences?

Tags: machine-learning, conferences

What are the most significant annual Machine Learning conferences?

Rules:

1. One conference per answer
2. Include a link to the conference

Answer (score 7):

[**ICML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICML) (International Conference on Machine Learning)

- [ICML 2010](http://icml2010.haifa.il.ibm.com/)

Answer (score 7):

[NIPS (Neural Information Processing Systems)](http://nips.cc). It's actually an intersection of machine learning, and application areas such as speech/language, vision, neuro-science, and other related areas.

Answer (score 5):

[AISTATS](http://www.aistats.org/) -- Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics

Similar flavor of papers to NIPS, although papers may be of slightly lower quality. It is much smaller than ICML or NIPS, which allows people to have deeper interactions.

Answer (score 1):

[AAAI (in Atlanta this year)](http://www.aaai.org/Conferences/conferences.php)

Answer (score 1):

[Artificial Intelligence In Medicine](http://aimedicine.info/aime/) (AIME), odd years starting from 1985.

Answer (score 1):

[European Conference on Machine Learning and Principles and Practice of Knowledge Discovery in Databases (ECML PKDD)](http://www.ecmlpkdd2010.org/)

To see the type of papers presented at the conference see the videos of the last confenece on [videolectures.net](http://videolectures.net/ecmlpkdd09_bled/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the only machine learning conferences for those in Australia and New Zealand is:

- [23rd Australasian Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence](http://ai10.cis.unisa.edu.au/)

It's held in Adelaide this year.

Answer (score 0):

[European Symposium on Artificial Neural Networks, Computational Intelligence and Machine Learning](http://www.dice.ucl.ac.be/esann/)

Answer (score 0):

[IEEE World Congress on Computational Intelligence](http://www.wcci2010.org/topics/ijcnn-2010). Note that it is the link for 2010 conference.

Answer (score 0):

[International Conference on Artificial Neural Networks](http://delab.csd.auth.gr/icann2010/). Note that the link is for the 2010 conference.

Answer (score 0):

[International Conference on Robotics and Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Conference_on_Robotics_and_Automation)

- [ICRA2015](http://icra2015.org/)
- [ICRA2016](http://www.icra2016.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[IEEE/RSJ International Conference on Intelligent Robots and Systems](http://www.ieee-ras.org/conferences-workshops/financially-co-sponsored/iros)

- [IROS2015](http://www.iros2015.org/)
- [IROS2016](http://www.iros2016.org/)